# Received errno EMLINK while using connect() function

Tags: c, linux, sockets

To communicate with BLE device, i have used Bluez library on Linux OS. But when i run my code, sometimes i received fail status while connecting with device. Please see this function:

```
static int l2cap_le_att_connect(bdaddr_t *src, bdaddr_t *dst, uint8_t dst_type,
                                    int sec)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_l2 srcaddr, dstaddr;
    struct bt_security btsec;

    if (verbose) {
        char srcaddr_str[18], dstaddr_str[18];

        ba2str(src, srcaddr_str);
        ba2str(dst, dstaddr_str);

        printf("btgatt-client: Opening L2CAP LE connection on ATT "
                    "channel:\n\t src: %s\n\tdest: %s\n",
                    srcaddr_str, dstaddr_str);
    }

    sock = socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to create L2CAP socket");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set up source address */
    memset(&srcaddr, 0, sizeof(srcaddr));
    srcaddr.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    srcaddr.l2_cid = htobs(ATT_CID);
    srcaddr.l2_bdaddr_type = 0;
    bacpy(&srcaddr.l2_bdaddr, src);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&srcaddr, sizeof(srcaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to bind L2CAP socket");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set the security level */
    memset(&btsec, 0, sizeof(btsec));
    btsec.level = sec;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_BLUETOOTH, BT_SECURITY, &btsec,
                            sizeof(btsec)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set L2CAP security level\n");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set up destination address */
    memset(&dstaddr, 0, sizeof(dstaddr));
    dstaddr.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    dstaddr.l2_cid = htobs(ATT_CID);
    dstaddr.l2_bdaddr_type = dst_type;
    bacpy(&dstaddr.l2_bdaddr, dst);

    printf("Connecting to device...");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &dstaddr, sizeof(dstaddr)) < 0) {
        perror(" Failed to connect");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    printf(" Done\n");

    return sock;
}
```

The problem is, the connect() function return -1, and the errno is EMLINK
I read many documents but i can not find the reason of this bug. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: do you think it make EMLINK error?

Comment: I am not familiar with bluetooth stack except superficially so I did google this, turns out there is not much about this, just found http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.bluez.user/3917

Comment: Well, [`EMLINK is bluetooth error 0x9`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1b1050cdc5cdde43177b375b5f22dc070d45d8f8/net/bluetooth/lib.c)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: "*do not cast ...*" what would be the alternative here ...?-S

Comment: @Viet sorry :D I have been seeing too many unnecessary casts, and this did look like one, but it is not, alk is correct :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: it mean my code is right?

Comment: Since you do not close the socket properly at the end of your program, the kernel closes it forcibly, which might mean it will linger for a while. This is necessary, because if a connection is shut down without proper agreement *of both parties*, the connection cannot be reused until the kernel is sure no packets belonging to that connection are still in flight -- otherwise a new process would receive bad packets, from an old connection it has nothing to do with. ...

Comment: ... I would wager you have compiled and ran your program quite a few times, and only suddenly (or spuriously) see the error. If so, the reason is that you are using up all connections, and the kernel does not have any "unused" ones to hand to your process; they're all "lingering". To fix, always close your sockets properly, so that its resources can be immediately reused by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel maps Bluetooth [error code `0x9` to `EMLINK`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1b1050cdc5cdde43177b375b5f22dc070d45d8f8/net/bluetooth/lib.c). Bluetooth error `0x9` means "too many connections". Perhaps your device do not support any connections of these kind, or in your attempts you've opened too many connections and now it still thinks they're still alive.

Disclaimer, I am not a Bluetooth expert.

Comment: i think connect() is function of socket? Is it wrong?

Comment: yes it is; `connect` manuals do not say about `EMLINK`; it must be specific to L2CAP

Comment: i have reviewed my code. When the process is exited, i do not close the sock. Do you think this is the reason of EMLINK error?

Comment: I am not sure; usually the sockets should be closed at process exit; you should make sure you close the socket as soon as possible.

Comment: The function you link returns `EMLINK` for `10` as well.